# How to position a Button dead center using LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, center

I am trying to set my Buttons, which are underneath a TextView, to be dead center of the screen.
At the moment, I only got them to be the horizontal center, but not vertical center, so the Buttons are right underneath the TextView, which is not what I want.
I have even tried using layout_gravity instead of gravity, but still no luck.

Here is what I got

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="CALCULATOR"
    android:id="@+id/appTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button android:text="BASIC MATH"
    android:id="@+id/basicMath"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="BASIC ALGEBRA"
    android:id="@+id/alg"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="BASIC CALCULUS"
    android:id="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="INFO"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can try to wrap the Buttons into a `<RelativeLayout>` and to Center them using the `android:layout_centerInParent` Attribute to `true`.

Comment: Do you have any mock up means what should be the final view you want?

Comment: Could you define "dead center"?

Comment: In your first Linear layout set height to be match_parent
   

android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Thank you all for you inputs, I never knew that using nested layouts should be avoided -- I will keep this in mind for future programs. However, since this is not really a serious project of mine, I think I'm going to stick with @L-X answer, since it is the easiest fix for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't suffer **nested layouts**, sorry.
Therefore I **really had to** suggest an alternative.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <TextView
        android:text="CALCULATOR"
        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
    <!-- All you need is a little trick -->
    <!-- This dummy View is invisible, but it's CENTERED -->
    <!-- The 4 Buttons will be positioned in RELATION to this one -->
    <!-- This is the power of RelativeLayouts -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/vwDummy"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent"true"
    />
    <!-- These 2 are horizontally centered and go above the dummy -->
    <Button
        android:text="BASIC ALGEBRA"
        android:id="@+id/alg"
        android:layout_above="@id/vwDummy"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="BASIC MATH"
        android:id="@+id/basicMath"
        android:layout_above="@id/alg"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <!-- These 2 are horizontally centered and go below the dummy -->
    <Button
        android:text="BASIC CALCULUS"
        android:id="@+id/calc"
        android:layout_below="@id/vwDummy"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
    <Button
        android:text="INFO"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_below="@id/calc"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As illustrated in the comments, I take advantage of the **relativity** of a RelativeLayout's children.
All you need is a little trick:

- Create an invisible dummy View in the center.
- Align the 4 Buttons in RELATION to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Update your layout as follows:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="CALCULATOR"
android:id="@+id/appTitle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
/>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 >

<Button android:text="BASIC MATH"
    android:id="@+id/basicMath"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="BASIC ALGEBRA"
    android:id="@+id/alg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/basicMath"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="BASIC CALCULUS"
    android:id="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/alg"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />

<Button android:text="INFO"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calc"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    />
</RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can get rid of the nested RelativeLayout, since it's really not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a RelativeLayout as parent and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to you `LinearLayout` which wraps the Buttons. Also the width and height of the `LinearLayout` should be set to `wrap_content`.

You could achieve the following result:

[image]

The following xml was used:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="CALCULATOR"
        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button android:text="BASIC MATH"
            android:id="@+id/basicMath"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button android:text="BASIC ALGEBRA"
            android:id="@+id/alg"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button android:text="BASIC CALCULUS"
            android:id="@+id/calc"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button android:text="INFO"
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just an advice at the end: 
use LinearLayout `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` since it is deprecated since API 8

Comment: You can get rid of the nested LinearLayout, since it's really not needed.

Comment: You are right. Nested layouts should be avoided due to performance issues. But I am sure this wont lead to performance problems. I think it is easier to understand this way, cause the questioner also used a LinearLayout in the xml. Feel free to post an other solution.